# Parse push notification android issue

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use parse push notification for my app. According to the parse document i registered phone as

```
if(ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("MyPhone") != null 
   && ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("MyPhone").toString().length() > 0) {
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().remove("MyPhone");
}
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().add("MyPhone", Session.getInstance().user.userNumber);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

when i push from parse it recieve to the device and in parse it also show sent to 1 user. But sometimes it doesnt recieve to mobile device and i check the push log. That phonenumber register in push with id but it shows send to 0 users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you remove your phone from the Installation..

Comment: @Neeks I just tried to remove already installed id from my phone for different user scenorio..And also i added that phone number again to parse for update latest phone id in parse. Please check my question I updated.

Comment: Are you using GCM on your app ? I had the same issue months ago and it was due to GCM.

Comment: yes i am using gcm also.

Comment: @Neeks how to resolve this issue can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to GCM. The trick that works for me was to add Parse GCM Sender ID when I register my app for GCM.

Right now, when you register for GCM, you might have something like this

```
gcm.register(YOUR_SENDER_ID);
```

Now, try to add Parse Sender ID this way :

```
gcm.register(YOUR_SENDER_ID, "1076345567071");
```